# SharePoint 2019 On-Premises Version: How to create contact list

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

We are transitioning from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019 On-Premises. We only have the standard version, not enterprise.  Is there an option or out of the box web part that can be used to create a contact list for a department sub site, that would pull from a SharePoint list that contains employee names, departments, phone numbers, and that would not require us to have that same list in our of our department sub sites.

Right now, the list lives in our top site on the home page, but I can't access the employee list from the sub sites. Our company doesn't use active directory. I'd like to create a contact list from a list that resides on the same domain URL, but will be placed on a sub site.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off adding this information to user accounts in Active Directory and then synchronising this information to SharePoint profiles via the User Profile Synchronization service in SharePoint central administration.

[Manage user profile synchronization in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/manage-profile-synchronization)

This way, you can use the People web part, to display information about users. This information will be available across all SharePoint sites.